# How to serve react-create-app build with nginx on server without domain name (only IP)?

Tags: reactjs, http, nginx, serve

I am asking for how to configure nginx. For now i tried some variations and stack on this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  root /srv/appfolder/build;
  index index.html;
  server_name my_server_ip_without_http;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
~
```

Now- when i hitting the server IP i got :

> Welcome to nginx!

For now I am trying only http for beginning.
Is it possible to make it work in format IP:port/pagename ? or IP:pagename?
Is it possible to serve several apps on different ports and enable app page uri work?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to work with the [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic), in addition configure your .htaccess to be compatible. Example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: The OP asked about Nginx. Nginx supports neither `.htaccess` nor the configuration format you show.

Comment: Yes. It's a example. Nginx use a type file .conf. So, check what corresponds to this in Nginx.